# Перегрузка операторов, строковое представление

Tags: python, ооп, перегрузка-операторов, python-2.x

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cost, level):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.level = level

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return Command(self.cost + other.cost, max(self.level, other.level))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{u.name} (cost={u.cost}, level={u.level})'.format(u=self)


class Command(object):    
    def __init__(self, cost, level):
        self.cost = cost
        self.level = level

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Employee):
            return Command(self.cost + other.cost, max(self.level, other.level))

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Command (cost={b.cost}, level={b.level})'.format(b=self)


emp1 = Employee('Ivan', 12, 4)
emp2 = Employee('Sidor', 15, 6)
emp3 = Employee('Joe', 26, 8)
com1 = emp1 + emp2
print com1
```

Как сделать, чтобы метод `__str__` возвращал (как и где прописать инстансы)

```
'Command (cost=27, level=6) [Ivan (cost=12, level=4), Sidor (cost=15, level=6)]'
```

вместо

```
'Command (cost=27, level=6)'
```

?

Comment: Ну пожалуста удалите мой вопрос@Nicolas Chabanovsky

Comment: вы сами можете удалить свой вопрос (если очень хочется)

Comment: не могу так как на него есть ответ, только модератор может @PashaPash

Answer (score 2):

Ваш класс `Command` ничего не знает о том, кто в нём состоит.

Довольно простое решение, которое мне видится, это использовать кортеж внутри `Command` для хранения всех `Employee`.

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cost, level):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.level = level

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return Command(self, other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{u.name} (cost={u.cost}, level={u.level})'.format(u=self)


class Command(object):    
    def __init__(self, *employees):
        self.employees = employees
        self.cost = sum(employee.cost for employee in employees)
        self.level = max(employee.cost for employee in employees)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Employee):
            return Command(other, *self.employees)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Command (cost={b.cost}, level={b.level}) {b.employees}'.format(b=self)


emp1 = Employee('Ivan', 12, 4)
emp2 = Employee('Sidor', 15, 6)
emp3 = Employee('Joe', 26, 8)
com1 = emp1 + emp2
print com1
```

Здесь вывод будет следующий:

```
Command (cost=27, level=15) (Ivan (cost=12, level=4), Sidor (cost=15, level=6))
```

Для этого я изменил способ создания объекта `Command`, сделал поля `cost` и `level` вычислимыми внутри класса, и для простоты примера, заменил перегрузку метода `__str__` в классе `Employee` на перегрузку метода `__repr__`. При желании несложно переписать так, чтобы использовался метод `__str__`.

Проблемой этого варианта исполнения будет то, что при создании нового объекта `Command` из `Command` и `Employee` будут снова пересчитываться поля `cost` и `level`, хотя можно использовать значения уже существующего объекта `Command`. Это, при желании, не так сложно исправить.

Хотел также напомнить, что использование перегрузки операторов может породить трудночитаемый код, так как сокращает возможность указания дополнительной информации о действии до знака оператора. Название метода даст гораздо больше информации и будет гораздо понятнее для читающего. Поэтому правильнее использовать перегрузку только в тех случаях, когда она действительно упростит читаемость кода.